# C++ LibVLC dos it work?

Tags: c++, c, libvlc

I would like to use LibVLC in C++, but looking in the documentation I saw that a version named LibVLCpp existed.

Only impossible to find it. Does LibVLC work in C++ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does LibVLC work in C++ ?

Yes, you can use it like any other c-API in c++.